# Is there a way that Excel can choose the two largest items in one category, and subtract them?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am working with county level data where counties are organized by FIPS codes, and there are multiple candidates per county (example provided below).

[image]

For each FIPS code, would like Excel to look at the candidate that has the most votes, and subtract from it the candidate with the second most votes. If the FIPS codes for two rows are identical, the second--and all proceeding rows--should not yield any result, until such a point that the FIPS code changes again. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why the code below does not work?

```
=IF(C1<>C2,MAX("Votes" AND("FIPS"=C30))-LARGE("Votes" AND("FIPS"=C30),2),"")
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Your question seems incomplete. There are certain unique FIPS codes. Do you want the difference between the FIPS code with the highest votes and the FIPS code with the second highest votes? And do that for each unique FIPS code?

Comment: Output would be the result of the subtraction in the cell that the code is typed into.

Comment: Check my edited comment.

Comment: Example: Imagine FIPS Code 001 has three rows, with votes of 1000, 750, 200. Then the fourth through sixth rows are for FIPS Code 002, with votes of 500, 600, 700. If I paste that code on every line, I would like it to tell me "250" on row 1 and "100" on row 4, while leaving the rest of the rows blank. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Can you maybe give me an example?

Comment: How did you compute the values "250" and "100" ? Did you do 1000-750 and 700-600 ?

Comment: Yes, precisely. The largest value in each category minus the second largest.

Comment: Could you post the result with your formula? Maybe with a google sheet link if possible.

Comment: Because as of now, the only way I see is to compute largest and second largest values for each FIPS code separately and then find the difference by subtracting.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1A4NiW2tSJ8EtTY50zxl01BJj55BEbgSMK4vgIZVmX4M/edit#gid=0

Comment: In that case, how would I go about finding the largest value for each FIPS code?

Comment: So your formula isn't working because you are using functions incorrectly, you need to pass parameters that they require with commas wherever required. e.g there is no comma in your MAX() function.

Comment: Ok thank you; I'll take a look!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is calculate the largest and second largest votes for each FIPS code separately and then find the difference by subtracting.

Structure of sheet and values:

[image]

Formulas:

[image]

IMPORTANT NOTE: For the formula to find the second largest, remember to use **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** instead of just Enter. You need to do this because it is an array based formula rather than just a normal formula.